# Repeat group to match multiple occurrences

Tags: regex, go, regex-group

// The example is here: https://regex101.com/r/7kjJCr/3

I try to match strings of type `([0-9]):(([0-9]+)-([0-9]+))+`
Whereas the second group should be repeatable, so that a string like `25:12-54,213-512,1231-2344` gets matched and group in (25, 12, 54, 213, 512, 1231, 2344) and a string like `25:12-34` should be processed the same way.

I appreciate any ideas!

Comment: No, repeated captures are constantly overwritten, and only the last value is kept.  You only have as many groups in the result as you have defined in the pattern.

Comment: You need to use `([0-9]+):([0-9]+-[0-9]+(?:[,/][0-9]+-[0-9]+)*)` and when a match is obtained split the contents of the second capturing group and add these items to the result.